# How to find a basis for the kernel of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $W = $Span$\{1,\sin(x),\cos(x), \sin(2x),\cos(2x)\}$ and I have a linear transformation $T: W\to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as:
$T(f) = \left[ { \begin{array}{c}
f(0) \\ f(\pi/2) \\ 2f(0)-f(\pi/2)
\end{array}
} \right]$

So to find the kernel, I have to find $f \in W$ such that $f(0) = 0$, $f(\pi/2) = 0$, and $2f(0)-f(\pi/2) = 0$.

And here's where I don't know how to proceed. I think I'm looking for.

Is this correct: $f(0) = 0 \to f(x) = \sin(x)$ or $f(x) = \sin(2x)$

$f(\pi/2) = 0 \to f(x) = \cos(x)$

$2f(0)-f(\pi/2) = 0 \to f(x) = 2\sin(x)-cos(x)$ or
 $f(x) = 2\sin(2x)-cos(x)$.

So the basis for Ker $T$ is then:

$ \{ \sin(x) \cos(x) (2\sin(x)-\cos(x)),$

$\sin(x) \cos(x) (2\sin(2x)-\cos(x))$

$\sin(2x) \cos(x) (2\sin(x)-\cos(x))$,

$\sin(2x) \cos(x) (2\sin(2x)-\cos(x))
\}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you take product of basis elements?

Comment: I thought I had to find an element for each of the equations (and also that the end product had to be from $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Product is not defined for vector spaces.

Comment: You're missing a lot more vectors as I've pointed out in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: an element of $W$ has the form

$f(x)=a_1+a_2\sin(x)+a_3\cos(x)+a_4\sin(2x)+a_5\cos(2x)$.

We have: $f \in ker(T) \iff f(0)=f(\pi /2)=0$.

Hence $f \in ker(T) \iff$

$0=a_1+a_3+a_5=0$ and $a_1+a_2-a_5=0$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying.

Comment: I wish you good luck !

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out, thanks to help I received from @Kenny Lau

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_1=1,a_2=\sin x, a_3 = \cos x, a_4 = \sin 2x, a_5 = \cos 2x$.

Assign vector $e_i$ to $a_i$ ($e_i$ is a column vector of $0$s with $1$ at $i$th place) and realize that any $f(x) = b_1 + b_2\sin x + b_3\cos x + b_4\sin 2x + b_5\cos 2x$ can be written in vector notation as $\sum_{i=1}^{5}b_ie_i = [b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5]^T$.

Now, let's find $T$ in matrix form by computing the transformations on basis.

$$
\begin{align}
T(a_1) &= [1,1,1]^T\\
T(a_2) &= [0,1,-1]^T\\
T(a_3) &= [1,0,2]\\
T(a_4) &= [0,0,0]\\
T(a_5) &= [1,-1,3]\\
\end{align}
$$

So, the $T$ becomes,

$$T = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0&1\\1&1&0&0&-1\\1&-1&2&0&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Finally, you need to find the null space of $T$ and then use convert the vector notation of null space to the corresponding functional notation as I showed in first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for the basis elements, $f(0)=(1,0,1,0,1)$, $f\left(\frac\pi2\right)=(1,1,0,0,-1)$, and $2f(0)-f\left(\frac\pi2\right) = (1,-1,2,0,3)$.

Note that $W$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^5$.

The matrix representation of $T$ is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0&1 \\
1&1&0&0&-1 \\
1&-1&2&0&3
\end{bmatrix}$$

According to [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=kernel(%7B%7B1,0,1,0,1%7D,%7B1,1,0,0,-1%7D,%7B1,-1,2,0,3%7D%7D)) (or by RREF), the kernel is generated by $\{-1+\sin x +\cos x, \sin 2x, -1+2\sin x+\cos 2x\}$.

The kernel has dimension $3$ because the rank of the matrix is $2$, as $2\mathbf r_1 - \mathbf r_2 = \mathbf r_3$ by definition of $\mathbf r_3$.

---

You have made quite a few errors:

- $f(0)=0$ gives us $f \in \operatorname{span}\{\sin x,\sin 2x,\cos x - \cos 2x,\cos x - 1\}$.
- $f\left(\frac\pi2\right)=0$ gives us $f \in \operatorname{span}\{\cos x,\sin 2x,1+\cos 2x,\sin x+\cos 2x\}$.
- $2f(0)-f\left(\frac\pi2\right) = 0$ gives us $f \in \operatorname{span}\{1+\sin x,-2+\cos x,\sin 2x,-3+\cos 2x\}$.

Each kernel has dimension $4$ because the rank is only $1$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get parts of it. I wrote up T as a matrix and row reduced it to $\left[ { \begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \end{array} } \right]$ and got $x_1 = -x_3 -x_5$ and $x_2 = x_3 +2x_5$ So I get that the kernel contains $(-1,\sin(x) + \cos(x))$ and $(-1,2\sin(2)+\cos(2x))$ Does it contain $\sin(2x)$ because $x_4 = 0$ (and hence is a free variable) ?

Comment: Yes, it does, as I have written in my answer.